# Get rid of [words] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) is really vague.  I can't imagine someone clicking on it because they wanted to know more about "words."  Should we get rid of it?

Comment: I'd like to ask if there has been anything done about this since June..."words" still seems to be around, and I think it's been made a synonym with vocabulary, but could we merge it? I agree, we should get rid of it ^.^

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) is vague, but I am not sure if we should remove it.  At least let me point out that it is different from the tags [japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) and [language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) because not all questions are about words.

Since one question can have only five tags, I would not hesitate to remove [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) to include more informative tags.  But if there is no more appropriate tag, I see nothing wrong with tagging a question as [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words).

Comment: Most of the time I think there is a more appropriate tag, like "word-choice" or "definitions."

Comment: @Amanda: What is the advantage of removing [words] tag?  There are currently 9 questions with this tag, but none of them has five tags.  As I said, I would not hesitate removing the [words] tag to add a more appropriate tag, but just removing it for itself sounds like a waste of time.

Comment: To decrease noise.  If a tag is ill-defined or not useful, then it should be a) replaced with a more apt tag, or b) removed because it is adding no information not conveyed by the other tags.

Comment: @Amanda: I do not see the [words] tag as a noise unless it is incorrect.  But I would not mind if someone removes the tag [words] tag when a question is already tagged with a more specific tag.  Just that I would not want to spend time doing so.

Comment: With the exception of the one question that has no other tag, removing the words tag doesn't seem to lose any information about what the question is about.  The other tags are already more focused and descriptive: translation, nuances, word-choice, numbers, etc.  And even the one question that is only words could be retagged as something else without much difficulty.